# Testing to see if a player is holding no item in hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to test to see if a player is holding nothing in their hand, so when you activate a sign (Wall Weapon, in my case) They are given a gun as long as they aren't holding anything. I have looked online for a while, and I really don't know how to Do this myself. If you know how to clear ONLY the item the player is holding, that is just as helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Also to mention, I did try to figure this out, so please do not disable question for not trying.

Comment: If you did try, why haven't you added that to your question?  Telling us you have, without displaying any effort, isn't really useful.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I meant I tried to find it online. I don't know enough about minecraft commands to do a lot with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` compound will only exist if the slot the player has selected on their hotbar contains an item. Therefore, you can mark the player as though they had no item first, and then remove that label if they actually had an item:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!EmptyHand] add EmptyHand
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=EmptyHand] remove EmptyHand {SelectedItem:{}}
```

And then target based on that label:

```
/say @a[tag=EmptyHand] has an empty hand.
```

---

For 1.8, you will need to use a scoreboard objective to track a score based on the player's data, though the principle is the same:

```
/scoreboard objectives add EmptyHand dummy
```

On a clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a EmptyHand 0
/scoreboard players set @a EmptyHand 1 {SelectedItem:{}}
```

For targeting:

```
/say @a[score_EmptyHand_min=1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am wondering why the add/remove is AFTER the @a, I always put it before.

Comment: @c15kenworthman It's a new feature of the `/scoreboard` command, unrelated to objectives. It's a simple string label to add or remove from the player. `/scoreboard players add` and `/scoreboard players remove` are for objectives, while `/scoreboard players tag` are for "tags".

Comment: That is 1.9, correct? I am using 1.8, and I can't use 1.9 for what I am doing.

Comment: @c15kenworthman Yes, "tags" are a 1.9 feature. You can use objectives for 1.8 instead, I'll update the post to include for 1.8.